# Performance of $rootScope.$new vs. $scope.$new

Tags: javascript, performance, angularjs

My current Controllers `$scope` is kind of thick with: `$watch` and event handlers.

On one point  I need to create a new scope for a modal, which does not have its own controller, because its quite simple. Still it needs a property of the current `$scope`. I was wondering which of the following solutions is better, and why?

a)

```
var modalScope = $rootScope.$new();
modalScope.neededValue = $scope.neededValue;
```

b)

```
var modalScope = $scope.$new();
// modalScope.neededValue already there
```

Should I be worried that the created `modalScope` will watch also those expressions and events? Any other aspects I should be aware of?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Option a) only copies the value once and doesn't keep it in sync with `$scope`, so it may cause confusing bugs. If your modal has a deep scope hierarchy then there are some cases where option a) might give you a very slight performance advantage (calling `$broadcast` on `$scope` means it needs to cover a smaller scope tree), but all in all I'd say option b) is the way to go.

Your `$watch`es won't really benefit from the location of the scope unless you're only `$digest`ing a particular scope.

EDIT: I see your modal is fairly light, in this case, definitely go with option b), the performance advantage from a) will be negligible.